# Visual Studio 2010 Web Deploy - slow and full of errors

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net, webdav, visual-studio-2010

When I say slow, I'm talking something like 10-30kb per second. And on some files larger than 1MB, I'll occasionally get errors like this:

```
3/18/2014 12:21:08 PM:C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
            EventType=Trace
            ArgumentType=Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentRetryEventArgs
            TaskName=VSMSDeploy
            Message=Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
            EventLevel=Warning
            EventData=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
3/18/2014 12:21:08 PM:        VSMSDeploy: Using ID '8178049a-c9a1-4bde-bdd0-07beaf7f5679' for connections to the remote server.
            EventType=Trace
            ArgumentType=Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentTraceEvent
            TaskName=VSMSDeploy
            Message=Using ID '8178049a-c9a1-4bde-bdd0-07beaf7f5679' for connections to the remote server.
            EventLevel=Info
            EventData=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
3/18/2014 12:22:10 PM:C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 2 of 10.
            EventType=Trace
            ArgumentType=Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentRetryEventArgs
            TaskName=VSMSDeploy
            Message=Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 2 of 10.
            EventLevel=Warning
            EventData=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
3/18/2014 12:22:10 PM:        VSMSDeploy: Using ID '1b4da8f4-6075-4fb3-b8fe-ddf0c8476803' for connections to the remote server.
            EventType=Trace
            ArgumentType=Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentTraceEvent
            TaskName=VSMSDeploy
            Message=Using ID '1b4da8f4-6075-4fb3-b8fe-ddf0c8476803' for connections to the remote server.
            EventLevel=Info
            EventData=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
3/18/2014 12:23:17 PM:C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 3 of 10.
            EventType=Trace
            ArgumentType=Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentRetryEventArgs
            TaskName=VSMSDeploy
            Message=Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 3 of 10.
            EventLevel=Warning
            EventData=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

As long as the file transfers successfully before attempt #10, the deployment continues. If attempt #10 fails, it stops and I have to restart it.

Nothing that I've found has really matched these issues exactly. Most people that get errors like these have firewall settings that prevent them from deploying at all, but my issue seems to simply be related to the absurd slowness of the process. The server is running IIS 7.5, and is not pegged for resources. Deploying barely has an impact on resources, actually. I feel like I'm missing something obvious - maybe a setting somewhere that is throttling the throughput on either the server or my local config... Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://alexjmackey.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/web-deploy-retrying-the-sync-because-a-socket-error-10054-occurred/

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841370/cant-get-my-ec2-windows-server-2008-web-stack-instance-to-receive-publishings

Comment: Both of those were issues where they couldn't even begin the deployment process, which is the one difference that I keep seeing (since I can deploy the majority of my files). I've tried everything suggested in those threads, but still no change in the results that I'm seeing.

Comment: Bummer.  Hmmm.  10054 is a winsock code for connection being reset by the peer.  What do your IIS logs and event logs have?

Comment: pretty much this for all of the failures: https://gist.github.com/asanger/8160b85502e0fbc12e4c . In my wmsvc logs, failed deploys get an sc-status 500 and sc-win32-status 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah. I use a mac as my dev station, and when I need to work with Windows I boot up a Virtual Box. After I tried deploying from a native Windows PC, I realized what my error was. My Virtual Box network was set to NAT. Changing this to Bridged completely resolved the issue. =\